# Rails 5: Stripe retrieve or create product

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to retrieve or create a product. My problem is that Stripe doesn't seem to find my Product and always creates a new Product, but a Product with the name 'Individuell' already exists.

My SubscriptionsController:

```
begin
 Stripe::Product.retrieve(@order.project) # name: Individuell
rescue
  Stripe::Product.create(
 name: @order.project, # name: Individuell
 type: 'service'
 )
end

private
 def set_order
  @order = Order.friendly.find(params[:order_id])
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the problem was that I thought `name` would be a unique identifier. Instead I added `id: @order.project` and then it worked.

So the code would like below:

```
begin
 Stripe::Product.retrieve(@order.project)
rescue
  Stripe::Product.create(
 id: @order.project,
 name: 'name',
 type: 'service'
 )
end
```